# CSS SVG filter issue: Hover effects work perfectly on localhost, but not on remote hosting/server

Tags: css, svg, web, hover, localhost

Hope anyone can help me resolving this problem...
So I have this peace of header in my index.html:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="application/xhtml+xml; UTF-8">
```

And I have this peace of code:

```
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 800 400" width="1600" height="800" style="enable-background:new 0 0 800 400;" xml:space="preserve">
  <defs>

    <filter id="whiteglow">
        <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="#ffffff" flood-opacity="1"></feFlood>
        <feComposite in="flood" result="mask" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in"></feComposite>
        <feMorphology in="mask" result="dilated" operator="dilate" radius="1"></feMorphology>
        <feGaussianBlur in="dilated" result="blurred" stdDeviation="1.33"></feGaussianBlur>
        <feMerge>
            <feMergeNode in="blurred"></feMergeNode>
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>

    <pattern id="pattern_EN" class="hexagon" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0">
            <image xlink:href="images/lang_en.svg" width="29" height="29" x="-2.5" y="-1"/>
    </pattern>
</defs>    
        <polygon id="lang_EN" class="st0" style="fill: url(#pattern_EN);" points="18.81692,32.33173 6.81692,25.40353 6.81692,11.54712 18.81692,4.61892 30.81692,11.54712
            30.81692,25.40353"/>

</svg>
```

And some peace of the CSS file:

```
#lang_EN:hover
  filter: url(#whiteglow);
  filter: url(/#whiteglow);
}
```

And now the interesting thing happens! When I use browsersync and watch my index,html file on the localhost, the :hover effect works perfectly!

**BUT**. After I upload all files on the web hosting, the :hover effect brakes absolutely in all browsers. So when I do hover on the elements, they just disappear, and come back to normal state after I mouseover these elements. I did a lot of things trying to fix it, and I broke my brains. Can anyone help me, please? :O

In brief: **CSS :hover effect applied on SVG element works perfectly on localhost, but does not work on web server (hosting).**

PS. I got grayscale filter, and it works. The trouble is :hover effect which does not work on the web server, but works locally.

PSS. Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/evileye/1daafqde/1/ 
and the same behavior

Comment: looks like the path is not right https://jsfiddle.net/1daafqde/3/ _remove the slash at front it stands inside the document itself, no need to go look where it stands_

Comment: that is fantastic... your fiddle works in FF, but when I upload it onto my web-site, it does not work T_T

Comment: Can you provide a link to the website, so we can compare it to the fiddles.